# Uploading name recordings into Outlook

Tags: windows, audio, outlook

**Question: Is it possible to even build a user friendly way to upload user created name recordings into Outlook contact cards?** Say through an Outlook plugin?

It looks like there is a feature on Outlook such that a contact can have a name recording as part of their contact card. This shows up in Lync automatically as well.

But based on what I see on the links below, it's quite difficult and not really feasible for normal users to do it.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/8e68d34f-8af3-4eee-b4f3-5bec7879af45/outlook-lync-contacts-spoken-names

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuuDq5tPpJ4

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/efad25b1-d153-471c-8429-784e0e15d8f7/how-do-i-set-speak-my-name-for-outlook-settings?forum=exchange2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do this with an add-in. There are also some existing tools out there that can do something similar with images; see: http://www.slipstick.com/exchange/cmdlets/import-images-active-directory/

Comment: Is there any way a user can add their own name's pronunciation?

Comment: You would have to develop something that uses PowerShell or have them run a script, as per: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351252.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396